# error: no value has been specified for this provider

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

When first time opening a Android project that is completely cloned from Gitlab  by AndroidStudio ,I met this "Gradle sync issue -- error: no value has been specified for this provider." problem Tips , Anybody has seen this ? what shall I do to fix it ? Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

This Problem is coming because your App is supporting a lower version of SDK and in Android Studio You installed the higher version,
which means if you cloned or download the app from GitHub then might be you faced this issue.
solution is-
go to Android Studio settings->Android SDK-> and check the lower version in which your Project is supported

Answer (score 0):

I also faced the same issue today and yes i tried the R. Desai's answer but my issue didn't solve. So, to fix this issue these steps worked for me..

1. Make a new dummy project File>New>New Project & **open this project in a new window**.
2. Go to **build.gradle(module)** and copy these variables' value`compileSdkVersion, buildToolsVersion, targetSdkVersion` from new project which you have just created  and paste these values in your old project.
3. Open **build.gradle(project)** and copy this variable's value `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle...` and paste it in your old project.
4. Open **gradle-wrapper.properties** copy `distributionUrl` and paste it in your old project.

Sync & Rebuild your project.

Finally my project is working now.